# How to play .wav from server file in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, embed, html5-audio, audio-streaming, absolute-path

For some reason I seem to be stuck on this. I am having problems playing audiophiles located on the IIS server.

- I have a hard time passing the file to the webpage player.
- I have a hard time getting the player to play it across major
  browsers(maybe I will be able to fix it with a jquery player) and
- I am having trouble setting autoplay to off.

```html
 <div id="divPickupPlayer" runat="server">
                       <embed src="..\..\wwwroot\SubDirectory1\Subdirecotry2\Upload\0123456790_1_P.wav" type= "audio/wav" />
```

The Source code file is located in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AppDirectory\Subdirecotry\Options.aspx
The AudioFile directory is  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SubDirectory1\Subdirecotry2\Upload\filename.

Eventually I am going to do from my server code:
divPickupPlayer = "embed src=FileNameVariable type= "audio/wav" />"

The FileNameVariable is stored in the db and includes the whole path "C:\directory\subdirecotry\abc.wav.

Thank you very much.  Also if you know a better way of accomplishing my goals :)
Thank you.

Comment: I added 

divPickupPlayer.InnerHtml = "<label> '" + AppPath + "'</label>"  to make sure that file path is correct.
So
<embed src="../../Directory1/Direcotry2/Upload/0123456790_1_P.wav" type= "audio/wav" /> seems to be a correct src path ???   wwwroot is not needed, but it's not playing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem, I was coding from my dev machine, I fixed it when I logged into the server machine.